# ViewFlipper : Receiver not registered

Tags: android, viewflipper, receiver

In my app sometimes I receive this error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@4806a4a8   
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:667)
at android.app.ApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:840)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:321)
at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:5891)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1076)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1570)
at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2565)
at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2535)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3498)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1867)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's this? What should I do? Need some help please...

Here is some code :

on `onCreate()` method I have this :

```
vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
        vf.setFlipInterval(3000);
        vf.startFlipping();
        populate();
```

where populate method is this :

```
private void populate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("lungime" + jArray.length());
            LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            l.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            vf.addView(l);

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Downloads/");

            File[] files = f.listFiles();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i].getPath());
            img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            System.out.println("target " + target[i]);
            img.setOnTouchListener(this);
            img.setId(i);

            l.addView(img);
            img = null;

        }
```

Comment: now I found this http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/05/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered.html . I am using a device cu version 2.1, so here looks to be the problem :(

Comment: I get this error if I don't keep the device on my hand on landscape mode. The app is only for landscape mode and if the device is kept on portrait mode I get a force close. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to [Daniel Lew's solution](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/05/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered.html), create this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class GabrielleViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
    public GabrielleViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public GabrielleViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        try {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            stopFlipping();
        }
    }
}
```

and in your layout don't use the normal ViewFlipper, use GabrielleViewFlipper:

```
<your.package.GabrielleViewFlipper
    .
    .
    .
</your.package.GabrielleViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this class to your project:

```
public class ContentViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
   public ContentViewFlipper( Context context ) {
      super( context );
   }

   public ContentViewFlipper( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
      super( context, attrs );
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
      try {
         super.onDetachedFromWindow();
      }
      catch( Exception e ) {}
   }
}
```

And then use it instead of the regular `ViewFlipper` in your XML:

```
<com.yourPackage.ContentViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**Edit**

As this problem seems to be specific to Android 2.1 (API 7), you can make sure you only target this change by copying the layout file(s) with the `ViewFlipper` to `res/layout-v7` and then changing the `ViewFlipper` to the `ContentViewFlipper` in those layouts. This way only devices running Android 2.1 will use the fix.

Comment: I think is not only for Android 2.1...it seems to appear on Android 2.2 too. It is working like this.