# Change between displaying different controls in App widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm developing an App widget. I want the widget to alternate between displaying a image and, displaying some text.

The layout is designed using a RelativeLayout like this....

```
<RelativeLayout ....>

<Textview.... />
bla bla....


<TextView...... />   <!-- First I want to display these textviews -->
<TextView...... />   <!-- First I want to display these textviews -->
<TextView...... />   <!-- First I want to display these textviews -->

<ImageView...... />   <!-- After nest update I want to show this image instead -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can I group these controls and hide/show these groups or do I have to handle all of them?
Maybe there is a better to do this? Different layoutfiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to use a ViewFlipper.  You can check out the docs here: [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

Comment: ViewFlipper is what I want, but I'm targeting api level 7 and I've read that its not possible in that version. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with view flipper in API7.  A quick google check brought up this workaround: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050730/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered]  Hope this helps